# What is the general pattern behind (dyadic) function composition's syntax?

Tags: kdb

The [Q Tips book](https://github.com/psaris/qtips) (Nick Psaris) shows the
following function (*Chapter 10*):

```
q)merge:`time xdesc upsert
```

As it is stated, it corresponds to function composition. I see the pattern: the
expression supplies a function that takes both arguments for `upsert` and then
uses its result to feed `time xdesc`. However the syntax feels weird, since
I would expect `upsert` to be the second argument of the `xdesc` invocation.

Aiming at simplifying the expression, I could see that the very same scenario
applies here:

```
q)f:1+*
q)f[2;3]
7
```

If we `show` its result, we can clearly see that `f` behaves as expected:

```
q)f
+[1]*
```

However, If we slightly modify the function, the meaning of the expression is
completely different:

```
q)g:+[1;]*
q)g[2;3]
'rank
  [0]  g[2;3]
       ^
```

In fact, `+[1;]` is passed as first argument to the `*` operator instead,
leading us to a `rank` error:

```
q)g
*[+[1;]]
```

I could also notice that the pattern breaks when the first function is
"monadic":

```
q)h:neg *
q)h[2;3]
'rank
  [0]  h[2;3]
       ^
```

Also here:

```
q)i:neg neg
'type
  [0]  i:neg neg
         ^
```

At this point, my intuition is that this pattern only applies when we are
interested on composing dyadic standard (vs user-defined) operators that exploit infix
notation. **Am I getting it right?** **Is this syntactic sugar actually more general?** **Is there any
documentation where the pattern is fully described?** Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some documented ways to achieve what you wish:

https://code.kx.com/q/ref/apply/#composition

You can create a unary train using `@`

```
q)r:neg neg@
q)r 1
1
```

https://code.kx.com/q/ref/compose/

You can use `'` to compose a unary value with another of rank `>=1`

```
q)f:('[1+;*])
q)f[2;3]
7
```

Likely the behaviour you are seeing is not officially there to be exploited by users in `q` so should not be relied upon. This link may be of interest:

https://github.com/quintanar401/DCoQ

Comment: Hi @rianoc thanks for your answer. I know that you can compose unary functions with `@` and the existence of the compose `'` operator. In fact, the links you've supplied are the most relevant entries when one searches for composition at kdb. However, my objective here is to identify this pattern: `f:1+*`, get access to related documentation and understand its limitations when taking it to other settings as is (instead of using additional operators).

Comment: I've been reading the second link in detail and I've seen that the pattern is actually located there, as "Implicit composition". According to the documentation, I still don't get why `neg *` isn't working, but at least I have something! :) Could you please (briefly) update your answer referring to such concept so I can approve this as the accepted answer?

Comment: I added a note on it being undefined/unexpected + a link to some other similar unsupported behaviours.

Comment: I’ve submitted a PR to the DCoQ repo that includes a warning not to use [exposed infrastructure](https://code.kx.com/q/basics/exposed-infrastructure/) in production code.